# All vs everything

Tags: grammar, word-usage, parallelism

Are "everything" and "all" interchangeable in these two cases? I'm having a hard time choosing between them.
 1) You must tell me all/everything about your holiday.
2)I am having a terrible day. All/Everything is going wrong.

Comment: Idiomatically, 'you must tell me all about your holiday' and 'everything is going wrong' are the more usual. 'Everything' is quantised; 'all' is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are interchangeable. As Nigel J mentioned in a comment, *everything* emphasizes a quantized *all*.

- *All* is use most often when generalizing all of the parts of the whole–

  It therefore emphasizes *the whole*.
- *Everything* emphasizes each part of the whole

  It therefore emphasizes *each part*. By the way, the *every thing* refers to *every part*. It is easy to remember that this is the quantized version this way.

## In practice

Both are correct, but do you really want to know every detail of the holiday? Probably not. Choose "*all*".

> 1) You must tell me all/everything about your holiday.

Here, *terrible* is an extreme. It makes sense to emphasize every little darn thing that went to heck. In other words, it makes sense to quantize each *thing* that went wrong. Choose "*everything*".

> 2)I am having a terrible day. All/Everything is going wrong.

Comment: It’s also worth noting that _all_ can often sound quaint or archaicising when used as a stand-alone subject, unless it’s quantified by a following relative clause: “All is wrong” sounds like something from out of the Bible, whereas “All I do is wrong” sounds like something you say in an argument with your significant other.

Comment: I say ”All is good“ regularly, like as a response to ”how‘ve you been?“. It does not seem archaic to me. I am sure I‘d use it in other contexts.

Comment: I think “all good” would be more common there; but note that I said **can** sound quaint or archaising. It isn’t necessarily, but it can easily be.